# how to make null value in a field in firestore document using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I want to make a field in firestore document to be null like `lastEventApproval` field in the image above.

I try to create a document by using the code below

```
let data = ["lastEventApproval" : nil , other data here .....]
batch.setData(userDictionary, forDocument: ref)
```

so I want to make when I successfully create a document, there is a field called `lastEventApproval` and the value is null like the image above

but the result is....

that `lastEventApproval` doesn't exist if I use that code. like this
[image]

in Android, I can make something like that using this code

```
val data = hashMapOf("lastEventApproval" to null)
batch.set(ref,data)
```

but I don't know why it doesn't work in iOS swift, maybe I need to asign other value than nil ?

so how to make a field in firestore document to be null in swift ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to actually write a null to use as a placeholder (for example) it's just this

```
func writeNull() {
    let collRef = self.db.collection("test_collection")
    let data: [String: Any] = [
        "key": "value",
        "key1": NSNull()
    ]
    collRef.addDocument(data: data)
}
```

and the result

[image]

This also works

```
func writeNull() {
    let collRef = self.db.collection("test_collection")
    let data: [String: Any?] = [
        "key": "value",
        "key1": nil
    ]
    collRef.addDocument(data: data)
}
```